# Looking for a function to using IF ELSE condition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table data with combination of Integer and strings. Like this

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId INTEGER,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  email TEXT NOT NULL,
  phone TEXT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (12345, 'Clark Duff', 'Sales@yahoo.com',9001234567);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (22245, 'Dave Johnson', 'Accounting@gmail.com',9000123456);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (55456, 'Ava evelene', 'Sales_Marketing@gmail.com',9000012345);
```

But I'm looking for a **common function** in MYSQL to check the condition whether it is a special character or integer or string. Below syntax will mask the data:

If it is an integer then this condition needs to execute:

```
concat(SUBSTRING(phone,1,3) , '*****' , SUBSTRING(phone,7,4)) phone
```

If it is a special character (@) then this condition needs to execute:

```
CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Mail`, '@', -1)) as Mail
```

ELSE string then other script

Comment: Which columns do you want to pass through this function? Is it just the email and phone fields?

Comment: `phone` is bigint, it can't store `123******789`, otherwise you can create a custom function using `RLIKE` and `CASE WHEN`, reading a text value and return masked text. But why not let application code to handle such logic

Comment: Yes email , Phone and name field @JimJimson

Comment: Phone numbers aren't numbers, they are a *string* of digits, you should fix your schema first and make all columns *varchar*.

Comment: When you say `is is a special character`. you actually mean to say `it contains a special character`?

Comment: @JamesZ I'm considering email address @ as special character

Comment: @Stu modified the schema

Comment: @mohan111 VARCHAR with appropriate size, not TEXT.

Comment: Why add the overhead of a centralised function? You already know the value is an email or phone number given the column name, just create a view and apply the exact criteria to each column.

Comment: What is unclear about the examples of [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) statements in the docs ?  why are you unable to apply those examples to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example [stored function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html). Is this what you mean?

```
CREATE FUNCTION `someFunc`(
    input VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF input LIKE '%@%' THEN
        RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(input, '@', -1));
    ELSEIF input REGEXP '^[0-9 ]{7,10}$' THEN
        RETURN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(input, 1, 3) , '*****' , SUBSTRING(input, 7, 4));
    ELSE
        RETURN input;
    END IF;
END
```

You may want to use `LEFT(MD5(input), 8)` instead of `LEFT(UUID(), 8)` so that the function can be declared as deterministic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `someFunc`(
    input VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF input LIKE '%@%' THEN
        RETURN CONCAT(LEFT(MD5(input), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(input, '@', -1));
    ELSEIF input REGEXP '^[0-9 ]{7,10}$' THEN
        RETURN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(input, 1, 3) , '*****' , SUBSTRING(input, 7, 4));
    ELSE
        RETURN input;
    END IF;
END
```

```sql
WITH `EMPLOYEE` (`empId`, `name`, `email`, `phone`) AS (
    SELECT 12345, 'Clark Duff', 'Sales@yahoo.com',9001234567 UNION
    SELECT 22245, 'Dave Johnson', 'Accounting@gmail.com',9000123456 UNION
    SELECT 55456, 'Ava evelene', 'Sales_Marketing@gmail.com',9000012345
)
SELECT
    empId,
    someFunc(`name`) AS `name`,
    someFunc(`email`) AS `email`,
    someFunc(`phone`) AS `phone`
FROM `EMPLOYEE`;
```

| # empId | name | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Clark Duff | b3282336@yahoo.com | 900*****4567 |
| 22245 | Dave Johnson | 47c44ab0@gmail.com | 900*****3456 |
| 55456 | Ava evelene | ab3fee5c@gmail.com | 900*****2345 |

Answer (score 2):

seem you are looking for case  statement applied  to like condition for @ char or cast to usingned  for chekc a valid integer number

```
select case 
  when email like '%@%' then CONCAT(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Mail`, '@', -1)) 
  when cast(phone  AS UNSIGNED) != 0 THEN concat(SUBSTRING(phone,1,3) , '*****' , SUBSTRING(phone,7,4))
  else 'not managed' 
end
```

Comment: I'm looking  for scalar function what ever the value IF phone  then that condition ELSE email then that condition. I want to use across Database

Comment: then  just use  the case properly  ..

Answer (score 2):

One UDF to mask them.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION fnMaskUserInfo (
>     input TEXT
> )
> RETURNS TEXT
> DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
>     IF input LIKE '%_@_%._%' 
>     THEN
>         RETURN CONCAT(RIGHT(SHA1(input),8),'@',SUBSTRING_INDEX(input,'@',-1));
>     END IF;
>     
>     IF input REGEXP '^[0-9]{7,10}$' 
>     THEN
>         RETURN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(input,1,3),'*****',SUBSTRING(input,7,4));
>     END IF;
>     
>     RETURN input;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT empId
> , fnMaskUserInfo(Name) AS Name
> , fnMaskUserInfo(email) AS email
> , fnMaskUserInfo(phone) AS phone
> FROM EMPLOYEE
> ```

| empId | Name | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Clark Duff | 1beb980f@yahoo.com | 900*****4567 |
| 22245 | Dave Johnson | 1dadfff9@gmail.com | 900*****3456 |
| 55456 | Ava evelene | 3a0768e7@gmail.com | 900*****2345 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=76a43cbf1a6da15ac6ef0fb371f7eb7d)*